# OSX Firewall: Forwarding Ports & Ignoring Non-Local Requests

Tags: network, security, firewall, webserver, websites

On my production Debian server I use this to forward requests that come in to port 80 to a non-root process running on port 8080:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

(The process is a Node.js cluster, but I doubt that it's relevant to this question.)

I develop on my Mac and am trying to build a more elegant environment for myself *without adding any unnecessary software to my computer*. I added an entry to my `/private/etc/hosts` file so I can use a pretty local domain:

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.dev
```

Now I want to access it without specifying a port. In other words, rather than `http://myapp.dev:8080`, I would prefer `http://myapp.dev`. I would also prefer not running my web server directly on port 80 so that it does not have root privileges.

I know my computer comes with a firewall, but I have not been able to find much information about it. So I'm looking for a **simple** way to forward anything coming to port 80 off to port 8080 like the IP Tables solution on Debian. I would most prefer to use the firewall that came with my computer and to set this up in the simplest way possible.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

***Bonus Points***: Is there a simple way to ignore all requests coming to port 80 (and 8080 for that matter) except those from my own computer on which the web server is running?

Comment: Mac OS X once utilized a utility called ipfw, but it was deprecated in favor of a port of BSD's pf. The documentation from Apple is available at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/pfctl

Comment: There are GUI tools that might help. For IPFW there is http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof and for PF there is http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor . I'm trying to get by without installing these as I'll probably never use them again.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, using IPFW, which co-exists with PF as of OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) is to simply run the command:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to me 80
```